# Passing EL expressions or managed bean instance in jsp:include

Tags: jsp, jsf, expression, el, jspinclude

I have a generic buttons jsp:

```
<wow:button id="addButton" iconClass="add16 icon16x16"
            action="#{managedbean.addNew}" type="submit" immediate="true"
            value="#{lblMsg.label_add }" />

<wow:button id="deleteButton" iconClass="iconCancel"
            action="#{managedbean.delete}" type="submit"
            value="#{lblMsg.label_delete }" />
```

This gets included in another jsp page via

```
<wow:outputText value="#{locationBean.disclaimer}"></wow:outputText> <br />
<jsp:include page="buttons.jsp">
```

This page has a managed bean instance used by the EL expression. I want to pass this instance of *locationBean* to buttons.jsp. One way is setting a param value in jsp:include to the bean name and using requestScope[beanName] in buttons.jsp.

Is there a better way?

Edit: wow is our own JSF component library.

Answer (score 2):

Using the legacy JSP, I don't think there are semantically better ways. Your approach might however break if you change the scope of the bean. Another way may be to use JSTL `c:set` instead.

```
<c:set var="currentBean" value="#{locationBean}" scope="request" />
<jsp:include page="buttons.jsp" />
```

with

```
<h:commandButton action="#{currentBean.action}" />
```

But this might clash with another beans which have by coincidence the same name.

Comment: I'll try this out tomorrow and post the answer. Thanks!